# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre size() y length en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estaba probando la diferencia entre `size()` y `length` en jQuery usando diferentes versiones, ya que según la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/length/) hacen lo mismo:

> **`length`**
>
> Returns: Integer
>
> Description: The number of elements in the jQuery object.
>
> The number of elements currently matched. The `.size()` method will
>   return the same value.

#### Caso 1: usando jQuery 3 `size()` da error:

```js
$(function(){
   console.log("Tamaño de li con size: "+$( "li" ).size());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Caso 2: usando jQuery 3 `length` funciona:

```js
$(function(){
   console.log("Tamaño de li con length: "+$( "li" ).length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Caso 3: Usando versión de jQuery inferior a la 3

Funciona tanto `size()` como `length`

```js
$(function(){
   console.log("Tamaño de li con size: "+$( "li" ).size());
   console.log("Tamaño de li con length: "+$( "li" ).length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

#### Pregunta

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `size()` y `length`? ¿Alguna recomendación para mantener el código actualizado?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `size()` y `length`?

Extracto de la documentación ([`jQuery.size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/)):

> The `.size()` method is functionally equivalent to the `.length` property; however, **the `.length` property is preferred** because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

En castellano:

> El método `.size()` es funcionalmente equivalente a la propiedad `.length`; sin embargo **es preferible usar la propiedad `.length`** porque no tiene la sobrecarga de una llamada a una función.

**Respuesta:**

Funcionalmente son equivalentes y devuelven el mismo valor, pero en cuanto a rendimiento `.size()` implica una llamada a una función que en su interior accede a la propiedad `.length`.

Por duplicidad funcional, y por razones de rendimiento, se consideró obsoleto `.size()` en jQuery 1.8 y se eliminó definitivamente en jQuery 3.0, por lo que aunque son equivalentes habría que evitar el uso de `.size()` para que el código funcione en versiones modernas y futuras de jQuery.

## ¿Alguna recomendación para mantener el código actualizado?

En la documentación puedes ver que fue marcada como obsoleta en la versión 1.8 (pero se seguía permitiendo su uso). Fue completamente eliminada en jQuery 3.0.

Documentación [`jQuery.size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/):

> `.size()`
>
> **Returns:** *Integer*
>
> **version deprecated:** `1.8`
>
> **removed:** `3.0`
>
> The `.size()` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the `.length` property instead.

En castellano:

> `.size()`
>
> **Devuelve:** *Entero*
>
> **version obsoleta:** `1.8`
>
> **eliminada:** `3.0`
>
> El método `.size()` está obsoleto a partir de jQuery 1.8. Use la propiedad `.length` en su lugar.

**Respuesta:**

Para mantener tu código actualizado siempre has de consultar los campos `deprecated` para saber si una función será eliminada en un futuro y cuál es su alternativa recomendada.

En tu caso, si no te percataste de que había que dejar de usar `.size()`, ahora tendrás que migrar código para mantener la compatibilidad con jQuery 3.0 o versiones posteriores (en el momento de escribir estas líneas era jQuery 3.2.1).

No te recomiendo usar "trucos" como definir la función en caso de no estar definida porque te seguirá creando malos hábitos que irás arrastrando en versiones posteriores y estarás, además, olvidando un motivo por el que se descartó el uso de `.size()` en favor de `.length`: duplicidad de funcionalidad (el motivo más importante) y rendimiento (aunque sea mínimo, apenas apreciable).

Answer (score 2):

Si no quieres *reformatear* todo el código cual usa la función `size()` puedes comprobar si existe y si no existe creas la función `size()`:

```js
// Comprobamos si existe la función size()
if ( typeof jQuery.fn.size !== 'undefined' ) {
   
  console.log('existe la función size');
}
else{
    // Creamos la función size()
    jQuery.fn.size = function() {
        return this.length;
    };      
}

$(function(){
    
   // Usamos size() en cualquier versión de jQuery
   console.log("Tamaño de li: " + $( "li" ).size());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

No estoy del todo de acuerdo con la respuesta de [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/98474/6491) respecto al rendimiento:

> No te recomiendo usar "trucos" como definir la función .... y estarás olvidando  un motivo por el que es mejor usar .length: **rendimiento.**

Si buscamos en el código de [jQuery 1.6.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js) donde se crea la función `size()` veremos que esta usando `.length`:
    ...

```
// The number of elements contained in the matched element set
    size: function() {
        return this.length;
},

...
```

No olvidemos, que `jQuery` es una [librería/biblioteca de JavaScript](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)

Ahora...

> ¿Alguna recomendación para mantener el código actualizado?

A veces se recomiendan aquí casos que en la vida real es imposible de realizarlo, por cuestión de tiempo y por su puesto el dinero y el *best practice* ni hablar.

Si tienes códigos que tienen más de **10** o **15** años... y el cliente no quiere actualizar todo el código entonces el rendimiento queda en segundo, tercer...o más plano.

A lo que voy,

- si la verdad es el gran tema de rendimiento: **no uses `jQuery`**
- si el cliente paga la inmigración de actualizar el código: **Adelante**
- si el cliente esta mal de tiempo y de dinero: **Usa el método cual sea para ti rentable**

Y por último, si queréis ver la diferencia en `size()` y `.length`, con el *"truco"* de crear la función `size()`, lo podéis hacer en el siguiente enlace:

**[Ver test de rendimiento size() vs .length](https://jsperf.com/fn-size-vs-length)**

Verán que es prácticamente lo mismo, a veces más rápido `size()` y a veces más rápido `.length`, ósea **insignificante**.

Mis 2 centavos (autsch).

Answer (score 0):

`size()` ya no se utiliza desde 1.8. Pero era el equivalente a `length` como bien has dicho.

Te copio desde la wiki y dejo el enlace: [size()](https://api.jquery.com/size/)

> The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length
>   property instead.
>
> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property;
>   however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have
>   the overhead of a function call.